# Spanish text in .py files

Tags: python, character-encoding

This is the code

```
A = "Diga sí por cualquier número de otro cuidador.".encode("utf-8")
```

I get this error:

'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)

I tried numerous encodings unsuccessfully.

**Edit:**

I already have this at the beginning

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Changing to

```
A = u"Diga sí por cualquier número de otro cuidador.".encode("utf-8")
```

doesn't help

Comment: You can have a look at http://farmdev.com/talks/unicode/ for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: there must be something you've left out? What OS are you running? What python version is installed? What text editor are you using? also see http://codepad.org/ZZgbOiw7 as this shows the answers below do work in python.

Comment: @James Khoury: The answers DON'T work if the source file is not encoded in UTF-8! Read my answer.

Comment: @John Machin Sorry thats not what I meant. I hadn't seen your answer and I was responding to the edit in the question. I was trying to get some more info which to help find out exactly what was happening.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Python 2?

In Python 2, that string literal is a bytestring. You're trying to encode it, but you can encode only a Unicode string, so Python will first try to decode the bytestring to a Unicode string using the default "ascii" encoding.

Unfortunately, your string contains non-ASCII characters, so it can't be decoded to Unicode.

The best solution is to use a Unicode string literal, like this:

```
A = u"Diga sí por cualquier número de otro cuidador.".encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: You haven't noticed the `0xed` in his error message :-( ... see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Error message:  `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)`

says that the 7th byte is `0xed`. This is either the first byte of the UTF-8 sequence for some (maybe CJK) high-ordinal Unicode character (that's absolutely not consistent with the reported facts), or it's your i-acute encoded in Latin1 or cp1252. I'm betting on the cp1252.

If your file was encoded in UTF-8, the offending byte would be not `0xed` but `0xc3`:

```
Preliminaries:
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\xed')
'LATIN SMALL LETTER I WITH ACUTE'
>>> uc = u'Diga s\xed por'

What happens if file is encoded in UTF-8:
>>> infile = uc.encode('utf8')
>>> infile
'Diga s\xc3\xad por'
>>> infile.encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
#### NOT the message reported in the question ####

What happens if file is encoded in cp1252 or latin1 or similar:
>>> infile = uc.encode('cp1252')
>>> infile
'Diga s\xed por'
>>> infile.encode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
#### As reported in the question ####
```

Having `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the start of your code does not magically ensure that your file is encoded in UTF-8 -- that's up to you and your text editor.

**Actions:**

1. save your file as UTF-8.
2. As
   suggested by others, you need u'blah
   blah'

Comment: Having `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` _in Emacs_ magically ensures you have UTF-8 encoding in current buffer...

Comment: @Xaerxess: As I said, it's uo to you and your text editor. Emacs is a text editor. It's not magic, it's called sensible code.

Comment: +1 What confused me first with your argument was the fact the both ``cp1252`` *and* ``unicode`` assign í to code point 0xed (237) - which I now think is merely coincidential.

Answer (score 1):

put on first line of your code this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: -1 It should be obvious from the error message that his file is NOT encoded in UTF-8. See my answer.

Comment: -1 for you @JohnMachin, I publish my response before you... if you want more point to help your reputation, do this helping another people, not give -1 for who just want to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your source file's encoding by adding the following line to the very beginning of your code (assuming that your file is encoded in UTF-8):

```
# Encoding: UTF-8
```

Otherwise, Python will assume an ASCII encoding and fail during parsing.

Comment: -1 It should be obvious from the error message that his file is NOT encoded in UTF-8. See my answer.

Comment: Firstly, it's not *obvious* unless you can interpret character codes in one look. Secondly, I said "assuming that your file is encoded in UTF-8". If it is not, all he has to do is to change "UTF-8" it with the actual encoding, *obviously*.

Comment: No, that's not all; he needs to add `u`. In any case, still -1: "fail during parsing" looks like this: `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xed' in file fnodeccp1252.py etc etc etc` -- *obviously* DIDN'T HAPPEN; he got a RUN-TIME error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably operate on normal string, not unicode string:

```
>> type(u"zażółć gęślą jaźń")
-> <type 'unicode'>

>> type("zażółć gęślą jaźń")
-> <type 'str'>
```

so

```
u"Diga sí por cualquier número de otro cuidador.".encode("utf-8")
```

should work.

If you want use unicode strings by default, put

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

in the first line of your script.

Look also in [docs](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html).

P.S. It's Polish in examples above :)

Comment: -1 It should be obvious from the error message that his file is NOT encoded in UTF-8. See my answer.

Comment: @John Machin: Forgot to add 'u' before string, that changes sense of my answer - I edited it, so it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

In the first or second line of your code, type the comment:

```
    # -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
```

For a list of symbols supported see:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_%28Unicode_block%29

And the languages covered: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want to do:

```
A = 'Diga sí por cualquier número de otro cuidador'.decode('latin-1')
```

And don't forget to add `# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: Please let me know if you need any help.